# Why wouldn't this program change anything, but the one below it does?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm studying pointers in C++ for an upcoming exam and I don't know why the first code here doesn't swap the values but the second one does. If anyone could explain to me why that would be great.

Why wouldn't this program swap the values of b[0] and b[1]:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void func1 (int* x, int *y)
{
    int* temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}

int main()
{
    int b[6] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    func1(&b[0], &b[1]);
    cout << b[0] << b[1];
}
```

but this one does:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void func2(int* x, int *y)
{
    int temp = *x;
    *x = *b;
    *y = temp;
}

int main()
{
    int b[6] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    func2(&b[0], &b[1]);
    cout << b[0] << b[1];
}
```

Thank you :D

Comment: in func2, when you write `b`, do you mean `y`?

Answer (score 1):

The explanation is that in the first case you are exchanging pointers to the values, not the pointed values themselves.
So you're manipulating addresses in the first case, while in the second case, you manipulate values.

Comment: and in the first case it is passing by values. so edchange the values of pointers wont change the actual pointers